# How to render an SVG onto a component from data array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, svg

I am storing my svg locally and then trying to de-structure it in the data file so that it can be rendered onto my card component when I spread the data as an object in the component.

There are no errors and it does load, however it does not display the SVG, just displays a default data fie as if the image cannot be fetched.

How do I get it to display properly whilst using a data array? link to the code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/13154fcdf8d)

Comment: use a web server. Browsers don't really support loading local files from other files. Note that I can't access your code sandbox, can you include the [mcve] in the question itself please?

Comment: Okay, so creating my own server would be the only way to render an SVG like that? are there no work arounds for local files?

Comment: You can disable all security on Chrome via various command line options but in that mode it's too dangerous to surf the internet.

Comment: @MicSt Please share your code here if you want help. Your CodeSandbox link needs us to create an account...